# 実数値の配列の最大値を返す関数

Tags: c

配列中の実数値をsize個分先頭から順番に出力する手続き、またその配列の要素を10個入力し、その配列の要素と配列中の最大値を表示するプログラムを書きたいのですが、下記に示すプログラムではそれができませんでした。

どこが間違っているのかもよくわからないので、わかる方がいましたら、回答よろしくお願いします。

```
/* size個 の入力された実数データを 配列の先頭から順番に格納する */
void readDoubleArray(int a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i＜size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%d 番目? ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }
}

/* size個 の実数データが入っている配列を 配列の先頭から順に出力する */
void printDoubleArray(int a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i＜size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%f ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//要素数size の実数をもつ配列 a の中の最大値を返す．

int maxDoubleArray(int a[], int size)
{
    int i,max;
    max=a[0];
    for(i=1;i＜size;i=i+1) {
        if (a[i]>max){
            max=a[i];
        }
    }
    return max;

}

int main(void)
{
    double data[1024];

    readDoubleArray(data, 10);
    printf("順番に出力:");
    printDoubleArray(data, 10);
    printf("最大値:%f\n", maxDoubleArray(data,10));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 期待する仕様に対して、現状のプログラムを動かした時にはどんな問題があるのかを **具体的に** 説明してもらうと、回答も付きやすいと思います。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: 関数名にDoubleを入れるくらいなら、引数をdoubleにした方が効果的だと思います。

Comment: たぶんコンパイルできてないですよね。「コンパイルするとこういうエラーが出ます。どうやって直すのでしょうか」と聞くのがよいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

`double[]` の中から最大値を探す関数は `int maxDoubleArray(int a[], int size)` ではうまくいかない（コンパイルエラーになる）でしょう。だってこの関数は `int[]` は受け取れるけど `double[]` は受け取れませんから。

関数や変数のネーミングはとても大事かつセンスがいります。名前見ただけで関数名と引数が矛盾していると思うようになれればいいですね。

```
double maxDoubleArray(double a[], int size) { ... }
```

のように書き換えるとうまくいくはず（未テスト）

# ツッコミどころは他にもいくつかあるんですけど本筋に関係なさそうなので略