# 実数値の配列の最大値を返す関数（2回め）

Tags: c

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60110/19110)でアドバイスいただいたように、

```
int maxDoubleArray(int a[],int size) {...}
```

の箇所を

```
double maxDoubleArray(double a[],int size) {...}
```

と直したのですが、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

> ````
> format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has
> type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]    scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
>           ~~^   ~~~~~
>           %d ex1205.c: In function ‘printDoubleArray’: ex1205.c:18:12: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2
> has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]    printf("%f ", a[i]);
>            ~^    ~~~~
>            %d ex1205.c: In function ‘main’: ex1205.c:43:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘readDoubleArray’ from incompatible pointer type
> [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>      readDoubleArray(data, 10);
>                      ^~~~ ex1205.c:4:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘double *’  void readDoubleArray(int a[], int
> size)
>       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ex1205.c:45:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printDoubleArray’ from incompatible pointer type
> [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>      printDoubleArray(data, 10);
>                       ^~~~ ex1205.c:14:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘double *’  void printDoubleArray(int a[], int
> size)
>       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ```
> ````

このようなエラーには、どう対処したら良いですか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のように直すと良いと思います。（**追記**: 表示結果が小数点以下切り捨てになっていた点も修正済みです。）

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* size個 の入力された実数データを 配列の先頭から順番に格納する */
void readDoubleArray(double a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%d 番目? ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }
}

/* size個 の実数データが入っている配列を 配列の先頭から順に出力する */
void printDoubleArray(double a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%lf ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//要素数size の実数をもつ配列 a の中の最大値を返す．

double maxDoubleArray(double a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    double max;
    max=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i=i+1) {
        if (a[i]>max){
            max=a[i];
        }
    }
    return max;

}

int main(void)
{
    double data[1024];

    readDoubleArray(data, 10);
    printf("順番に出力:");
    printDoubleArray(data, 10);
    printf("最大値:%lf\n", maxDoubleArray(data,10));

    return 0;
}
```

なお、次回以降で良いと思いますが、Stack Overflowで1つの回答で解決しなかった場合は、コメント等を使って引き続きやり取りすることができるので、元の投稿の回答者に引き続き答えてもらうのが、後々このサイトを見る人たちのためになると思いますよ :)

Comment: @user36412 新たな疑問について、[さらに新しい質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60141/%e5%ae%9f%e6%95%b0%e5%80%a4%e3%81%ae%e6%9c%80%e5%a4%a7%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92%e8%bf%94%e3%81%99%e9%96%a2%e6%95%b0-%ef%bc%93%e5%9b%9e%e7%9b%ae) を立てていらっしゃるようですが、こちらにコメントいただければ回答いたしますよ。

Comment: @user36412 新たなご質問の内容について、記載のコードを修正しておきました。